# Having issues with getting the candidate with the highest vote and his name using laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel

I Am trying to get from the candidate with the highest votes and his name also, all have tried runs false. I just dd() this below, after getting all the presidential candidates.

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#288 ▼
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => App\Candidate {#289 ▼
      #connection: "mysql"
      #table: "candidates"
      #primaryKey: "id"
      #keyType: "int"
      #attributes: array:9 [▼
        "id" => 1
        "name" => "Brian"
        "seat" => "president"
        "regno" => "DIT-C004-0536\2013"
        "votes" => 0     // this is the first candidate record, others are below.
        "user_id" => 2
        "created_at" => "2017-05-12 08:43:58"
        "updated_at" => "2017-05-12 08:43:58"
        "image" => ""
      ]

    }

    1 => App\Candidate {#290 ▼
      #attributes: array:9 [▼
        "id" => 5
        "name" => "Juma"
        "seat" => "president"
        "regno" => "DIT-C004-0516\2013"
        "votes" => 3
        "user_id" => 7
        "created_at" => "2017-05-12 09:03:03"
        "updated_at" => "2017-05-12 14:48:54"
        "image" => ""
      ]
    }

    2 => App\Candidate {#291 ▼
      #attributes: array:9 [▼
        "id" => 9
        "name" => "Stephen"
        "seat" => "president"
        "regno" => "0001"
        "votes" => 4           //trying to get the highest votes with the name.
        "user_id" => 12
        "created_at" => "2020-03-17 15:27:47"
        "updated_at" => "2020-03-21 19:18:39"
        "image" => ""
      ]
    }
    3 => App\Candidate {#292 ▼
      #attributes: array:9 [▼
        "id" => 10
        "name" => "Gobby"
        "seat" => "president"
        "regno" => "DIT-C004-0436\2014"
        "votes" => 0
        "user_id" => 11
        "created_at" => "2020-03-17 15:27:59"
        "updated_at" => "2020-03-17 15:27:59"
        "image" => ""
      ]
     }
```

I have been searching for solutions all around but couldn't find one, **Thanks in Advance**.

This is my controller:

```
{
    public function highestvote(){
    $getpres = Candidate::where('seat','president')->get();
    dd($getpres);
    foreach($getpres as $getpresvote){
        for($i = 0; $i < $getpresvote; $i++){
            $highv = $getpresvote[$i];
        }
    }
  return view('election.winners')->with('getpresvotes',$getpresvotes);

    } 
}
```

I die dump the code before looping, cause when I loop it keeps on giving me 0 or sometimes tells me stuff like array can't be converted int.

Comment: post your controller code as well!

Comment: Did you try..  - >max('votes') on your collection?

Comment: @nikistag it instead returns 0. am surprised

Comment: The answer below is a solution... Order by votes desc and get first result. Still there is a problem if two candidates have the same no of votes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Controller Code should be like this in this case:

```
$seat = 'president';
$name= 'gobby';
$data = Candidate::where('seat', $seat)
                  ->where('name', $name)
                  ->orderBy('votes','desc')
                  ->first()
print_r($data);
```

It will give you the maximum votes data with the seat 'president' and name 'gobby'